# what is the best configuration for visual studio 2010 working with and SSD

Tags: ssd, visual-studio-2010

Maybe these are stupid questions but I should ask anyway, I think must people agree that SSD are a good investment for programming, although this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362/best-laptop-keeping-visual-studio-in-mind) is two years old it has a lot of up votes. My laptop is getting stuck when I open a lot of programs, photoshop (taking 2GB RAM), visual studio (500MB RAM) and others... Firefox for example (500 MB RAM), sometimes I have 100MB free of my 4GB RAM memory and 4Gb page file used. That's why I am really thinking in buying an SSD, seems that hard drive is a bottle neck.

My questions is, since SSD are degraded with writes, should I put my solution on the SSD or in an external hard drive? Will Visual Studio benefit putting the data on an external hard drive? I am  sure that must of you use SSD, how do you use it?

Edit

Seems the short answer is put everything in the SSD and ensure having Trim technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"SSD are degraded with writes" is now *mostly* a myth*

Windows 7 has built-in TRIM support and most modern SSDs practically eliminate these early issues (3rd party software or internal work to clear/garbage-collect unused pages). [Anandtech](http://anandtech.com) and [Tom's Hardware](http://tomshardware.com) have some great articles and write-ups on the subject. The core issue is that "clearing" a flash page is a relatively long operation; if this is done ahead of time or in the background there is *no appreciable degradation* (the memory itself does not get slower over time). TRIM lets the OS tell the drive when a page can be cleared/recycled -- as far as the SSD (or HDD) is concerned, a page consisting of nothing but zeros is still valid data.

**Put everything you want fast, INCLUDING OS, SOFTWARE, AND SWAP, on the SSD**. (This naturally extends to Visual Studio projects and pretty much anything else except for large media or archives :-)

I would recommend an SDD based on the SF-1200 (or higher) series ~ $200 or less for 120GB. Except for capacity and cost, there is *no reason* to ever go back to spindles -- **a good SSD is so fast at random access, that even under moderate-heavy load swap is "almost unnoticeable" or "minimized to the point where it does not bother me".** (An SSD is still significantly slower at random access and throughput then main memory, however. Being good at swap is a stop-gap and not a real solution for a demanding user.) In this aspect there is absolutely *no contest* between an SSD and HDD in terms in of random-access performance and latency: a good SSD will win hands-down in every test/scenario that favors this usage pattern and even a good HDD will make a system chug under moderate-heavy swap. With everything else equal, I would get a good SSD over another 4GB of memory, but best would be to get both ;-)

Data read sequentially, like movies or large archives, will see the least benefit moving from platters to flash chips (but will *still see a benefit*) -- once a HDD gets going it has a pretty high throughput. In this aspect the role of HDD's is relegated to the task of *mass storage* and not *every minute usage*.

I will never willingly not have an SSD as a primary drive again. Even a "degraded SSD" (say, 80% optimal) is still *much faster* than an a conventional HDD  -- but remember, that just like a traditional HDD, a SSD will eventually get old (and "slow" in relation to current technology) and fail -- **use it while you have it and keep external backups**. Also, not all SSD's are equal. Again, my recommendation is an SF-1200 (or higher) based device -- it is just a "consistently good" prosumer controller for a competitive price (throughput isn't everything, consider average/max latencies, etc).

Now, get to a techie site, read a few articles, and put in an online order for a shiny new toy :-)

---

*If it really is a myth depends upon the actual SSD controller/firmware, operating system configuration/support, external maintenance tools, etc., of course. Windows 7 comes with TRIM support and the SandForce (e.g. SF-1200/1500/2xxx) controllers are TRIM-aware; they are also fairly aggressive at internal collection and page-cycling. With *good* controllers and TRIM support the statement "SSD are degraded with writes" really does become a myth.

Answer (score 2):

> My laptop is getting stuck when I open a lot of programs [...]

## You need more **RAM**.

Buying an SSD to make your *page file* faster is simply ignoring that fact. It's a waste of an SSD, and doesn't even give you the same boost as RAM.

#### Also: Please *do not* say "virtual memory" when you mean "page file" or "swap file". :(

Comment: Regardless of being able to benefit from more RAM, it is *not* a waste of an SSD :-)

Comment: @pst: IMHO it is -- you buy an SSD to speed up *file* access, not to substitute for lack of RAM. Buying it for that purpose is just a waste.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes. And as a side-effect, in my experience, it speeds of swap *tremendously*.

Comment: @pst: Did you mean speed "up"? If so, then yes, but in my experience, RAM is even faster and cheaper. :P

Comment: @Mehrdad yes, typo :) RAM is indeed quite cheap for a 4GB upgrade, and it is *much faster* at being RAM. I am not opposed to more memory and think it is warranted -- however, the speed difference at random file access between an SSD and HDD is staggering.

Comment: @Mehrad, when you open a lot of programs at the same time the OS will mash the poor HDD with many read requests - RAM is not going to help much.

Comment: @iconiK: What do you think *causes* the thrashing in the first place?

Comment: @Mehrdad, thrashing has nothing to do with the OP's issue. The OS needs to read from storage to load those programs, storage which is horribly slow, which is why the HDD is the single biggest bottleneck in a system. Once you've removed the HDD you can talk about more RAM so you don't hit swap.

Comment: @iconiK: But what makes you think those programs all need the HDD at the same time? And why did the OP mention RAM in the first place?

Comment: @Mehrdad, the fact that the OS needs to load the executable code when he opens them all at the same time, or in quick succession.

Comment: @iconiK: But what makes you think he's opening them at the same time?  My impression was that he's *using* them at the same time, not necessarily opening them simultaneously. (After all, a fresh start of Firefox doesn't use 500 MB of RAM.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: "My laptop is getting stuck when I *open* a lot of programs."

Comment: Interesting discussion, actually I am using my programs at the same time, so it made think in more RAM but my laptop only supports 4GB RAM, so I need a new one or get an SSD to solve my problem, I vote up both questions but finally select the one from pst, thanks for sharing, btw i edited my post to change virtual memory for page file ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the hard drive is truly your bottleneck, a SSD will definitely be of help.  I have one of these:

http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/internal_storage/Mercury_Extreme_SSD_Sandforce

The difference in this line of SSD drives is that they don't get slower over time.  This helps me maintain my speed even though I use the drive as my primary system drive.  SSD leveling also helps with the speed over time issue.

As for the speed difference, I use a Mac with VMWare Fusion running my Windows (I develop primarily in Visual Studio).  My Mac boots incredibly fast.  In fact, my wife has a similar Mac without a SSD (but she has a 7,200 RPM drive).  My Mac can boot into the OS, boot Fusion, boot my Windows and be in Visual Studio before hers comes to the login screen.

In short, I find a SSD to be EXCELLENT for development work.